# WordPress Installation Error - Reports Database Does Not Exist, But Exists

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost

When installing WordPress, you can see that a database called WordPress has been created, with all root privileges.
The language is in Portuguese because it's my native language, okay?

[image]

The name of the database as WordPress was written, with the correct username and password:
[image]

But it shows the message: "Can’t select database
We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the wordpress database":

[image]

But the wordpress database was already created in the phpMyAdmin, as shown in the first photo.

Please, what to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phpMyAdmin screen is showing that you have decided to run your MySQL on a non-standard port of 3307 (the default is 3306). You'll need to tell WordPress to connect to the correct port.

I believe that WordPress follows the `host:port` syntax, so you can probably use `localhost:3307` as the value for the "Database Host" value.